# Web text part missing text, but images remain

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

We have a new employee page that has text and the employee's image. After a certain number of new employees the web text part is missing text. I am able to recover the text from the version history, but this keeps happening. Does anyone know the cause of this?

Comment: What web part did you use?

Comment: The text field.

Comment: Could you please provide detail steps about how did you add the image in text web part?Per my knowledge, we could not add image in text web part in SharePoint online.

Comment: The image was not added in the text web part. The images remained, however the text web part disappeared as you scrolled further down the page.

Comment: According to my test, although the text web part will add some images below, it will not disappear, please create a new page and add the text web part and image to check the result